# Wildfly10 mod_cluster multiple port clustering. 404 on call context

Tags: apache2, wildfly, mod-cluster

I have configured wildfly to listen on different ports for webservices and jfs-pages.

Maven jsf module jboss-web.xml:

```
<server-instance>client-web-application</server-instance>
<virtual-host>client-web-application</virtual-host>
```

Maven webservice module jboss-web.xml:

```
<server-instance>webservice</server-instance>
<virtual-host>webservice</virtual-host>
```

standalone-full-ha.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <server name="client-web-application" default-host="client-web-application">
            <http-listener name="client-app-listener" socket-binding="client-app"/>
            <host name="client-web-application">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>            
        <server name="webservice" default-host="webservice">
            <http-listener name="webservice-listener" socket-binding="webservices"/>
            <host name="webservice">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>            
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
    </subsystem>
    ...
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public">
    <socket-binding name="client-app" port="7998"/>        
    <socket-binding name="webservices" port="7990"/>        
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    ...
</socket-binding-group>
```

This configuration works fine untill i try to make cluster configuration. I have configured jgroupup and apache with mod_cluster. Cluster is formed I can see it in logs, mod_cluster_manager also shows the list of connected nodes and published contexts.

And here is the problem. When i try to call webservice address or some web page i get 404 from Wildfly. I assume that this is caused by putting ajp-listener to the default-server because when I moved it to client-web-application web pages works fine.

How should I configure it? Should i make two ajp-listeners and 2 VirtualHosts on mod_cluster in apache?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to create the listeners for each server in wildfly, and a separate balancer in apache, yes.